# Slow WPF Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, serial-port

I am developing a simple serial data viewer that will be used to watch the data being transmitted to one of a computer's serial ports. I wrote a test application using C# and WPF; it simply places the most recently read line into a textblock. However, it skips every-other line. My theory is that new data is being put into the textblock before WPF renders the window. However, I've tried every combination of thread priorities I can think of and, at best, the application shows every other line; at worst, it shows every 20 lines.

I am running on a multicore computer. My application consists of a textblock and a button to open/close the port. (I have tried replacing the textblock with a textbox, and I observe the same problem)

My *DataReceived* handler:

```cs
private void MainWindow_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string message = sp.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
        return;

    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {
        text.Text = message;
        this.InvalidateVisual();
    });
}
```

The highest priority for this application is to handle sustained throughput of a lot of data; is WPF appropriate in this situation? If it is, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried just creating a public string Message property, implementing INotifyChangedProperty, and binding the textbox directly to the message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of my companies products is displaying "near real-time" updates of data from a server, and there are a couple of things you can try....

You might be able to move your text.Text outside of the dispatcher call if you databind it instead of directly setting it.

you can do this like so:

add a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageTextProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("MessageText", typeof(string), typeof(MyWidowClass), 
    new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

        public string MessageText
        {
            get { return (int)GetValue(MessageTextProperty ); }
            set { SetValue(MessageTextProperty , value); }
        }
```

on your xaml textbox:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MessageText, ElementName=xNameOfMyWindow}"/>
```

where xNameOfMyWindow is the x:Name attribute of your window tag

now your code would like this:

```
private void MainWindow_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string message = sp.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message))
        return;
    this.MessageText = message;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One more question - if I wanted to store all of the incoming data into a textbox, what would you recommend as a storage container for the data? I have heard StringBuilder, List<string> and LinkedList<string>, but can I bind any of these to a textbox?

Comment: Oh, and a note for future readers: the line "this.MessageText = message;" needs to be wrapped inside an invoke, as the serialport calls the event handler from a separate thread.

Comment: @CWMan the spparate thread was information i was not aware of! thanks!

Comment: @CWMan your best bet for storing would probably be an ObservableCollection<string> (watch for threading issues) and then use a ListBox and bind to the ItemSource, instead of a TextBox

Comment: I'd love to, but the users of the application need to be able to select text like a normal textbox. I don't believe a listbox can do that?

Comment: @CWMan here is what you do, then.  set the ItemTemplate for the list box item to be a TextBox (kind like this): <ListBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><TextBox Text="{Binding}"/></DataTemplate></Listbox.ItemTemplate>

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is really late to the game here, but after struggling with this issue for about a month now, I stumbled upon the source of my problems with slow textbox updating:

Turning off textwrapping completely removed my UI locking problem:

TextWrapping="NoWrap"

This, of course, will mean that you'll need to be more responsible for ensuring your strings are wrapped properly before updating the textbox via Environment.NewLine, but its a small price to pay in my opinion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solved the problem for us too. Gave us a performance boost of maybe about 100 times better.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late, but I ran in this problem.
What I've found it's that SpellCheck Property seems to slow down text entering in WPF Textboxes. Since I needed spell check, I worked around this issue adding a simple Forms.Timer: when the user starts writing, the textchanged event of the textbox disables spell check and starts the timer. Then, when one second is passed, the tick event of the timer enables spell check.
Now textboxes are fast as they should be.
Hope this can help someone with this frustrating issue.