# WPF TextBox performance

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, xaml, mvvm

I am developing an application which retrieves data in a separate thread. A delegate is 'called' within the thread to get the data in a viewmodel. A string property will be used to set the text of a WPF TextBox (databinding).

**ViewModel**

```
private string _resultText;
public string ResultText
{
    get
    {
        return _resultText;
    }
    set
    {
        _resultText = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Name="tbxResult" Text="{Binding ResultText, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Padding="10,10,10,10" IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

The thread is retrieving a lot of data, which causes a performance issue. The UI is freezed until all data is retrieved. I already tried to use the Binding IsAsync="True" property, TextWrapping="NoWrap", calling the Dispatcher.Invoke in the setter of ResultText and checked the question ['slow-wpf-textbox'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228289/slow-wpf-textbox).

None of the provided solution improves the performance.

Executing the following code causes the same (performance) issue:

```
private void btnRetrieveResultData_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++)
    {
        tbxResult.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            tbxResult.AppendText("testMessage" + i);
        });
    }
}
```

What is the solution/ implementation to handle a lot of data and display it in a TextBox? (It could be another control which provides scrolling and the option to select text).

Comment: Do you actually want the textbox to update in real time (as in, for the user to see the changes as they come)?

Comment: I prefer real-time, but a slight delay isn't bad. (e.g. if I display a progress percentage, it doesn't matter if it jumps from 0% to 15%).

Comment: In the absence of a better solution, you could just cache the string changes as they come along, and update the textbox as often as you want. So when your thread brings in changes, update a string instead of the property that the textbox uses.

Comment: And by "as often as you want" I mean using a timer or something like it, to trigger N textbox updates per second, where an update is `textBoxText = cachedText;`

Comment: So you are adding a lot of text to textbox or replacing it with high frequency?

Comment: @Evk At this moment, I am changing the 'ResultText' with high frequency.

Comment: Just your example is adding text, and you also want scrolling capabilities. But what't the point to replace text with high frequency, user still won't be able to keep up with changes?

Comment: @Evk I would like to retrieve the data as fast as possible. The user can scroll through the data while retrieving. I implemented the AutoScroll feature of ['Autoscroll Textbox if user has not moved the scrollbar'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897937/autoscroll-textbox-if-user-has-not-moved-the-scrollbar).

Comment: Yes but you said you are replacing text, not adding. Or by replacing you mean something like `ResultText += "something"`?

Comment: @Evk In code, I keep adding data (strings) to a StringBuilder. After an .AppendLine, I set the ResultText = stringBuilder.ToString().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem but I will use "Executing the following code causes the same (performance) issue", changing `i` to 300.000 to add more text to textbox. Changing that to:

```
   private void ButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
                tbxResult.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {
                    tbxResult.AppendText("testMessage" + i + "\r\n");
                }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
            }
        });
    }
```

Adds lines to textbox in a very fluid fashion without any UI freezes and you can actually manually scroll textbox while items are being added.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting property of TextBox to IsReadOnly="True" then i suggest please use TextBlock instead of using the TextBox because,
Textbox uses 30 element to become an control while textblock uses only 1.

Comment: The advantage of using a textbox is that text can be selected and copied. In some conditions like displaying debug infos, readonly database content, textbox is a better options.

Comment: yes i understand, but i suggested to use the same in context of performance . of course choosing control depends on requirements.